# Fibonacci Spiral vs Golden Spiral?

Tags: trigonometry, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QBeKyznwk0) video on constructing the Fibonacci Spiral.  Does it differ from the Golden Spiral?

The Fibonacci Spiral is constructed by using arcs of a circle on consecutive squares where the lengths of each correspond to the Fibonacci Sequence.  I note that the sides of consecutive squares increase by the Golden Ratio.

I tried superimposing a [Golden Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral) using $r = \varphi^{2\theta/\pi}$ over the following image (from prior link) and I could not get the curve to fit.  Is there a particular part of the image that should be the polar graph origin?

[image: a]

Answer (score 1):

These spirals can't match exactly since the Fibonacci spiral has circular arc segments and the radius of the golden spiral changes constantly. The former is an approximation to the latter.

Comment: Is there equation for the Fibonacci spiral?  I think Fibonacci numbers can be found using the Golden Ratio in powers

Comment: If a pair of consecutive Fibonacci numbers are e.g., $(8,13),$ the clockwise spiral has spacing 8 and the anticlockwise 13. Spiral equation tends to $ \rho=d \cdot \varphi^{2 \theta/\pi}$, $\varphi$ is the GoldenRatio.

Comment: There's no single formula for the Fibonacci spiral since it is pieced together by circular arcs.

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4853496/can-the-fibonacci-spiral-be-expressed-as-a-polar-equation.

Comment: @EthanBolker You are incorrect, for a closed form solution for the Fibonacci spiral see my answer to a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4853496/can-the-fibonacci-spiral-be-expressed-as-a-polar-equation.

Comment: @CyeWaldman That solution is just a piecewise formula disguised by incorporating the Heaviside function. I choose not to call that "closed form".

Comment: @EthanBolker Well, we might disagree on that. But would you agree, at least, that it is a *single formula* for the Fibonacci spiral?

Comment: @CyeWaldman If that's a "single formula" then any function of a real variable defined piecewise on intervals can be described by a similar single formula. So I would not refer to yours that way. Tastes differ.